# Click event inside conditional statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click

I want a click event to only be available when a condition is met. #space02 is not clickable until the condition is met. But after the condition is met and reset, #space02 is always accessible even when ready == 5 is false. What accounts for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/v4C5h/9/

```
<body>
    <div id="space01">Click First</div>
    <div id="space02">Click Last</div>
</body>
```

---

```
var ready = 0;

function count() {
    ready++;
}

function resetCount() {
    ready = 0;
}

$('#space01').on('click', function() {
if (ready < 5) {
    count();
    console.log(ready);
} else if (ready == 5) {
  $('#space02').on('click', function(){
       resetCount();
    })
}
```

Comment: Well you have to unbind the event if you dont want it to be able to be used..

Comment: Not going to help but using ready like a global variable is bad practice.

Comment: @tymeJV Dont need to unbind the event, could just disable or readonly

Comment: @Sebastien $('#space02').unbind('click'); after resetCount() does accomplish what I wanted. Is there an advantage to using .prop('disable'...) over .unbind?

Comment: In fact i am not quite sure what are the advantages... maybe someone else could clarify this?

Comment: A friend actually helped me with an obvious solution that takes the event outside of the condition. $('#space02').on('click', function() {
  if(ready == 5){
    resetCount();
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#space01').on('click', function() {
    if (ready < 5) {
        count();
        $("#space02").prop('disabled', true);
        console.log(ready);
    }else if(ready == 5){
        $("#space02").prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $("#space02").prop('disabled', true);
    }        
});

$('#space02').on('click', function(){
    resetCount();
});
```